# How to get WordPress to send Password Reset Link Email instead of New Password?

Tags: security, password

My WordPress configuration generates a new password and sends it via email whenever a user uses Forgot Password link.

How can I make WordPress send a Reset Password link instead of a new password?

I want this so that malicious visitors can't use the Forgot Password link on the site and enter someone else's email address to cause an unwanted password reset for that user.

Comment: The default behaviour is to receive a link to change the password. Maybe you have a plugin that's modifying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commentor was correct. A plugin had changed default behavior.